# The effect of listener execute multiple times

Tags: java, libgdx, actionlistener

When i click SelectBox first time and type some key, then my method CreateAutoComplete is execute one time. When i unfocus SelectBox and click again and type some key, then method execute two times. Next three times... four...

Of course i want only one time everytime.

```
private SelectBox<String> sbNationality;
private AutoComplete auto = new AutoComplete();
...
sbNationality.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {   
        addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyTyped(InputEvent event, char character) {
                auto.CreateAutoComplete(sbNationality, character);
                return super.keyTyped(event, character);
            }
        });
        super.clicked(event, x, y);
    }
});
```

Comment: The only thing your listener on `sbNationality` does, is assigning another listener to, I suppose, your class object. Thus, every click adds another listener for `keyTyped` action. Why don't you just add that inner listener normally, without putting it's addition into another listener?

Comment: Can u show me what to do this? How to add keyTyped into clicked method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example, most likely not meeting your requirements, but should give you the general idea.

```
// Add this field as a flag for you to know whether the sbNationality has been clicked or not.
private Boolean isSbNationalityClicked = false;



// On click, set the flag to true
sbNationality.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
        isSbNationalityClicked = true;
        super.clicked(event, x, y);
    }
});


addListener(new ClickListsner(){
    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(InputEvent, char characer){
        // if you caught the keyTyped event and the flag is true - perform your desired action
        if(isSbNationalityClicked){
            auto.CreateAutoComplete(sbNationality, character);
            // set flag to false, since the desired action has been executed
            // you might want to set flag to false in some other cases as well,
            // like mouseReleased or mouseLeave
            isSbNationalityClicked = false;
            return super.keyTyped(event, character);
        }
    }
});
```

Using the code above, once your `sbNationality` gets clicked, it'll set the flag to `true`, so no matter what you do meanwhile, `keyTyped` listener will act like it was clicked. You might wanna catch some other events like `mouseReleased` or `mouseLeave` to handle the value of `isSbNationalityClicked` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Your listener is registering a new listener at each click event, this is why you get duplicate actions.

It sems that the `ClickListener` you use, has a `keyTyped` method which is what interests you (the key typed event), not the click event by itself, so try this :

```
addListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean keyTyped(InputEvent event, char character) {
                auto.CreateAutoComplete(sbNationality, character);
                return super.keyTyped(event, character);

           }
});
```

Comment: I just suggested some piece of code, please have a look.

Comment: That code is not working. My method CreateAutoComplete dont execute when i press some key.

Comment: Edited again, your code shows that you want to register the key listener to the current component, not sbNationality.

Comment: This code is working, but i want execute this method only when im click my SelectBox sbNationality.